# Stokes theorem on $C^1$ manifolds?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, stokes-theorem

I have recently encountered Stokes theorem on embedded submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and I didn't manage to find a proof for $C^1$ vector fields over $C^1$ manifolds, infact I have only seen that proof for $C^1$ vector fields on $C^2$ manifolds.

Now, it seems to me that lots of the special cases of stokes theorem (such as the divergence theorem) can be generalized to $C^1$ manifolds and I'm starting to wondering if the general case works also for such manifolds.

Does anyone have a reference, or maybe is so kind to write a proof himself, for such a generalization of the theorem, or, conversely, knows a counterexample?

Thanks in advance and excuse me for my english, I hope the question is clear enough.

Comment: On a $C^k$ manifold, a vector field is at best $C^{k-1}$. Perhaps you mean a $C^1$ vector field on an ambient $C^2$ manifold? See Michael Taylor’s *Measure Theory and Integration*, Appendix I, for the divergence theorem for $C^1$ vector fields on Lipschitz domains $\Omega\subset\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: You are right, I confused a couple of traductions. I guess now my question is: is there a generalization of Stokes theorem that implies generalized versions of the 'Stokes type theorems', such as the divergence theorem? Thank you for the reference btw.

Comment: I’m sure they exist, I just don’t know precise references (except for the $C^1$ forms on $C^2$ manifolds case for which I wrote an answer once… but you already know this case). Afterall, in analysis, we have tons of ways of lowering regularity, and approximating results (weak derivatives, distributional derivatives, convolutions, Sobolev spaces etc), so you need to systematically extend these notions to manifolds then prove a general result there (balancing regularity of the boundary and regularity of the forms).